# Div getting pushed to the right when using float:left on it

Tags: html, css, drupal, layout, css-float

I'm currently creating a website and I came across a strange thing: I have a content div that's 950 width and centered on the page. Inside that I have a header div, a menu div and some other content div. I would like the menu div and that other content div to be right next to each other so I thought about using float:left on both divs. However, when I use this float:left on the menu div, it's getting pushed to the right and I can't figure out why. I think some other element is pushing it to the right.

I'm using a custom Drupal theme, a subtheme of Zen to create the page by the way.

Here's the HTML I'm using to create the page (without the header):

```
<div id="root">
<div class="content">
    <div class="left-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><p>Camera</p></li>
            <li><p>Audio</p></li>
            <li><p>Licht</p></li>
            <li><p>Lenzen</p></li>
            <li><p>Grip</p></li>
            <li><p>Accessoires</p></li>
            <li><p>Recorders</p></li>
            <li><p>Transport</p></li>
            <li><p>Edit suits</p></li>
            <li><p>Crew</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="products-overview">
    This is some other content that I want to the right of the menu.
    </div>

</div>
```

And here are some CSS properties I've set on left-menu and products-overview:

```
.left-menu {
margin-top: 10px;
background-color: #BBB;
width: 150px;
float: left;
}

.products-overview {
background-color: #BBB;
float: left;
}
```

Could anyone please explain me why the left-menu is being pushed to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I believe this is a result of the normalize.css stylesheet you're using.

The problem stems actually from the `.header` element, which has a table within it. The normalizing stylesheet has a `margin-bottom:1.5em` applied to the table, which translates into a margin on the `.header` element (since it has no padding/border), which in turn sends the `.left-menu` to the right (since the margin causes there to be no space for it to fit on the left).

Adding to your current `.header table` definition can fix this, with a simple:

```
.header table{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: damn you beat me too it ... I was just typing this

Comment: Great, this is working, didn't see that margin-bottom from the .header table, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem. I did and found a solution that should work. Just set the products-overview class to `float:none`. See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/yj4Uc/

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla Firefox it looks ok to me. From your code, I can only see that you need a width for the content div. and watch the dimensions, especially left/right padding and borders.

Comment: I've solved it by setting the margin-bottom to 0px of the .header table above the left menu. I'm working in Safari by the way and there it didn't look right ;)